# Number of ways in which the point can come out of the circle.

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $C_1,C_2 ,...$ $C_n$ be a sequence of concentric circles .
>   The $n^{th}$ circle has the radius $n$and it has $n$ openings. A point P
>   starts travelling on the smallest circle $C_1$, and it leaves it at an
>   opening along the normal at the point of opening to reach the next
>   circle $C_2$.Then it moves on the second circle $C_2$, and leaves it
>   likewise to reach the third circle $C_3$ and so on . Find the total
>   number of different paths in which the point can come out of the nth
>   circle.

Attempt: 
There are $n$ ways to come out of the nth circle, $n-1$ for $n-1$th circle...1 way for 1st circle. Thus, total number of ways = $n!$

But answer given is $n!\times 2^n$

How is my thinking wrong?

Comment: I find the problem a bit open to interpretation, but I guess that the point can move along each circle clockwise or counter clockwise. Hence the factor $2^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first circle we only have 1 opening, but there are two paths to get to that opening: clockwise and counter-clockwise. So $f(1) = 2$.

For the second circle we have two openings, and for each opening there are two paths to get to that opening: clockwise and counter-clockwise. So $f(2) = 4\cdot f(1) = 8$.

In general, for the $n$th circle we have $n$ openings, and for each opening there are two paths to get to that opening: clockwise and counter-clockwise. So $f(n) = 2\cdot n\cdot f(n-1)$.

Thus $f(n) = n! \cdot 2^n$.

Comment: What about turning multiple times around one circle? Wouldn't that generate an infinity of paths? I find the notion of _path_ subjective here. If the given answer were $n!$ there would be another explanation.

Comment: @anderstood Considering that exactly there are an infinite amount of paths if we allow self-overlapping paths, I think it's implied that that is not allowed.